# Validating psuedo xml file using Perl

Tags: xml, perl, validation

I have a file which has xml like tags and a bunch of invalid xml data because of which I cannot use a normal xml validators like xmllint on the the file. I want to ignore the invalid xml data and just check the file for well formedness.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HOST>
<VERSION>5</VERSION> 
<OUTPUT>
   bunch of text which also contains tags like  <SYSTEM> 
   more tags like <->   <temp>  & ; 
   some more text and numbers
 </OUTPUT>
</HOST>
```

In the above example can I just ignore tags like <system>, <->, &, ; etc and just check for valid opening and closing tags like <HOST> </HOST>  <VERSION> </VERSION> and <OUTPUT>
 </OUTPUT>. The above file should return back saying its well formed since all the valid tags have proper opening and closing brackets.

Can I create my own dtd/xsd ?? to look for the tags which I want and ignore rest of tags using Perl.

My main problem is that I dont know the right keywords to describe my problem which is why google is not giving me the right results. Can someone please push me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Is the invalid part always inside the OUTPUT tag?

Comment: yes.I just want to add that these files are huge some containing 10k lines.

Comment: You could add [`<![CDATA[]]>`](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) inside all the `<OUTPUT>` tags in some way. That would enable you to parse/validate the file with any proper parser. The problem is that you would have to do that in a way that is rather ugly.

Comment: I really dont want to write/modify anything in the file unless its a worst case solution. So I was thinking can I create my own xml which checks for the opening and closing tags and does not care whats inside the <OUTPUT> section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to clean up the input first. Once you do that, then you can do DTD, schemas, proper parsing, and whatever.

If it's just the `OUTPUT` tag, you can try this:

```perl
s/(<OUTPUT>)/$1<![CDATA[/;
s/(</OUTPUT>)/]]>$1/;
```

After that is done, your input should be ready for XML parsing, validation, etc. If your input might contain CDATA sections, you'll have to do more, but that should be enough to get started.

Comment: You don't have to do this to the file itself. You can apply that to the lines as you read them in and write them to a second file or just keep the rewritten version in a string.

Comment: I tried your code by making a temp file and then making the modifications on the temp file which was passed to xmllint and it did not complain. I am still a bit hesitant to use this approach. I was under the assumption that by creating my own XML schema with the tags which I want, I could validate the file easily without making any modifications. I thought that was the whole point of XML where you can create your own schemas. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: @sumedh data needs to be well-formed for any XML tool to be able to process it. You can't escape that.

Comment: @sumedh, but XML is a very, very particular format. It requires everything to be formatted correctly. If there's even a single parse error the XML tools out there will simply die. There are some tools that allow a bit of fuzziness, but I don't know of any DTD or schema tools that are that fuzzy.

Comment: There is another alternative you could try, which is to write your own parser that either generates the SAX events you need or a DOM tree that a DTD or Schema can operate against. However, writing a full blown parser for a custom format is probably well beyond an answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because the workaround which you have posted is doing the job. As a more permanent solution I will look into building my own custom parser which will build the tree which I want. Thanks Zostay

Answer (score 2):

May I ask what's the point? Your input file is not XML, and you don't want to make it XML by adding CDATA section. What do you gain by knowing whether "some" of the data is XML? It's not like you will be able to use XML tools on it, or that ypo will be able to deliver it as XML.

So really this non-validation doesn't gain you anything. Isn't it a bit of a waste of time then?

Comment: The file is later used for parsing and the parser stumbles when it sees that tags <OUTPUT> or <HOST> are not closed properly. The parser is able to read whats inside <OUTPUT> even though its not valid XML.

Comment: well then, use the (non-XML) parser to validate the format. Why pretend it's XML when it isn't?

Comment: If it is really that offensive, you can build a custom parser that builds a DOM tree or generates SAX events to fee into XML tools, but thats not something that can be given over in a short answer here.

Comment: I will look into building my own custom parser. The reason I posted the question here was because I did not know the right keyword to describe my problem. Thanks to your comment atleast I know what kind of keywords to look for.